# Value of type 'View Controller' has no member?

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, augmented-reality, viewcontroller

I am currently making an ar app using swift and Xcode. I was trying to set up a variable to check if a button was already being pressed. I have created the variable in the format I have seen other people recommend when answering similar questions but I keep getting the same 'Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'isActionPlaying' error.

```
var isActionPlaying: Bool = false                         -        attempted variable format to declare member

var tankAnchor: TinyToyTank._TinyToyTank?



class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    
    @IBAction func tankRightPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.isActionPlaying { return }                -         errors occur on this line
        else { self.isActionPlaying = true }              -         and this line

        tankAnchor!.notifications.tankRight.post()

    }
```

When trying to find answers to similar questions to help my own situation I saw many people suggesting a format similar to 'var isActionPlaying: String = "" ', but I believe I have followed this format and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... I saw many people suggesting a format similar to 'var isActionPlaying: String = "" ', but I believe I have followed this format and am still getting the same error.

You need to put the declaration of `isActionPlaying` *inside* the class definition. As you've shown it, it precedes the class definition, so it's just a global variable. Do this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    var isActionPlaying: Bool = false
//...
```